# XSL functx:pad-integer-to-length

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I'm very new to XSL - so I suppose this is an easy question...

I have an XML file I want to transform into Excel, everything works OK except one thing:
UserID may contain leading zeros, and leading zeros are stripped when importing to Excel - so I want to pad with leading zeros until I get a ten digit userID.
I found the function pad-integer-to-length - but there seems to be something more nedded?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <user>
    <xsl:for-each select="report/user">
    <xsl:sort select="substring(altID,8,4)"/>
        <patronline>
        <userID><xsl:value-of select="functx:pad-integer-to-length(userID, 10)"/></userID>
        <altID><xsl:value-of select="altID"/></altID>
        <sistafyra><xsl:value-of select="substring(altID,8,4)"/></sistafyra>
        <displayName><xsl:value-of select="name/displayName"/></displayName>
        <line><xsl:value-of select="address[@name='1']/entry[@name='Line']"/></line>
        <line1><xsl:value-of select="address[@name='1']/entry[@name='Line1']"/></line1>
        <line2><xsl:value-of select="address[@name='1']/entry[@name='Line2']"/></line2>
        <postalcode><xsl:value-of select="address[@name='1']/entry[@name='Postal code']"/></postalcode>
        <line3><xsl:value-of select="address[@name='1']/entry[@name='Line3']"/></line3>
        <email><xsl:value-of select="address[@name='1']/entry[@name='Email']"/></email>
        <note><xsl:value-of select="extendedInfo/entry[@name='Note']"/></note>
        <comment><xsl:value-of select="extendedInfo/entry[@name='comment']"/></comment>
    </patronline>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </user>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*UserID may contain leading zeros, and leading zeros are stripped when importing to Excel - so I want to pad with leading zeros until I get a ten digit userID.*" I don't understand this. If the UserID already contains leading zeros, why do you need to add them? And if the leading zeros are stripped when importing to Excel, then what point is there in adding them?

Comment: add a `'` character to the front of  your  userID so it is processed as a string in excel. Or probably surrounding the value in dbl-quotes will work (and be a more obvious solution to maintainers 3 yrs from now ;-) ) . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about a function in the library you can download from http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/download.html. So you would need to download http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xsl and use `<xsl:import href="library.xsl"/>`. Note however that only an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or like XmlPrime supports such a library as only XSLT 2.0 or later supports `xsl:function`.

If you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor then you will need to use a template based solution or explore whether it supports functions defined in EXSLT.

On the other hand, I wonder whether doing `format-number(userID, '0000000000')` might not suffice.